# Combobox not working properly while dragging the scrollbar

Tags: extjs, combobox

In the fiddle mentioned below, when I scrolls the combobox down and then tries to drag the scroll bar up, I am not able to click the Select All button. This happens in internet explorer.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1kn2

Comment: Which IE version ? It works for me on IE 11

Comment: You are correct pagep, it works fine in IE 11 with Windows 10 os.But when I use my test box with Windows server 2008 R2 with IE 11, it shows this behavior.Also the scroll bar shows abnormal behavior while dragging

Comment: Any fix would you suggest pagep?

Comment: It works for me on IE11 (11.0.9600.18537) on Win server 2008R2

Comment: This example seems to work now with ExtJs 6.5.0   https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/21e2